# R.java not being generated

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know this is very widespread problem , but I didn't find solution to my particular case after searching the web for almost one day. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have just installed eclipse , ADT and SDK. So I have tried followings but still I get the same error.

- Install all possible SDK build tools
- Delete gen folder and clean/build the project
- Fix all the errors in layout files
- Make sure that the path to sdk is correct
- Check if appcompat_v7 is added as a library or not

So what can you advise me to do besides these?

Comment: have you check other xml files? maybe you have an error in other xml file

Comment: I have only one empty activity with single layout file.

Comment: Check your minsdk version and Compile with sdk version. See if both are present and also check if min<Compile.

Comment: The file `R` will only be generated if there are no remaining compilation errors. Check the `error` view (commonly in tab above the console) for information about errors and warnings.

Comment: The only error is in the activity.java where I am using setContentView(R.layout.activity);. SHould I delete this too ?

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel Depends on the error. But for a quick fix, you could comment it by adding `//` before that line.

Comment: how will you see the output then. Make sure you have all your sdk installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I fixed by adding
`import your.package.name.R`
to my activity.

Eclipse by default adds `import android.R`

Comment: And how should adding the import statement fix the problem about a not generated `R` file? The error you mean is a different one.

Comment: Sorry , but This didn't fix the problem

Comment: Apologies. As Tom said, this solution is for a different error. R file should be generated if there are no more compilation errors. Check your res folder

Comment: No worries, jCoder. This Answer may not fix this problem, but it fixes a very common error, so you should keep it here :).

Answer (score 0):

You should try with NEXT

`rigth click in your projects -> Android Tools -> Fixed project libraries or support library project -> clean or restart.` If the above does not work, import the projects said JCODER

What you can also try is to change the android api

Hope that helps

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the xml, check it

Comment: I havent made any changes to the xml since it was generated after creating the project.So I'm sure that there cant be any errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to make sure all of your XML files are absolutely fine and have no errors.

If no errors found, try changing your Build Target and apply, then change it back. In eclipse do the following:

-> Project -> Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target -> Change the target and click Apply